# Does co_await in Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 works with std::experimental::optional

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, async-await

there are some links on the internet [[1](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2015/11/30/coroutines-in-visual-studio-2015-update-1/),[2]](https://partiallattice.wordpress.com/2016/01/31/c-co-routines-have-nothing-to-do-with-concurrency/) suggesting that co_await should work with `std::experimental::optional` and that VS 2015 Update 2 should support that. 
Since VS has no optional even in Update 3 I use I used the one from [github](https://github.com/akrzemi1/Optional), but the code like this does not compile:

```
optional<string> get_hope() {
    if ((rand() % 4) == 0)
        return nullopt;
    return "yolo";
}

optional<string> bla() {
    string s = co_await get_hope();
}
```

Error is:

> Error (active)        this co_await expression requires a suitable
>   "await_ready" function and none was found

So my question is am I doing something wrong, is library missing support for await or is the compiler missing support for this aspect of `co_await`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> there are some links on the internet [1,2] suggesting that co_await should work with std::experimental::optional

You're interpreting these links incorrectly. Though admittedly [this one is essentially *designed*](https://partiallattice.wordpress.com/2016/01/31/c-co-routines-have-nothing-to-do-with-concurrency/) to create this misinterpretation.

[P0057 "coroutines"](http://wg21.link/P0057) are essentially a way for a function to suspend its execution and be continued from the suspend point at some later time. The mechanism to cause this involves a series of complex interactions between the return type/signature of the function and the type of the expression being `co_await`ed on.

What people have discovered is a way to <strike>ab</strike>use `co_await` to perform the effective equivalent of a conditional return. You could have `co_await`, when applied to an `optional`, check the `optional`'s state and simply exit the function if it is empty. In effect, `co_await` would say to suspend the function (thus returning control to the caller), but *never schedule its resumption*. This creates the effect of a return (including cleaning up the coroutine) without actually writing `if(opt.empty()) return; else ...`. This also allows `co_await` to unpack the value from the `optional` if a value was stored in it.

However, that doesn't just magically happen because `optional` exists. You have to build special `co_await` machinery that works with both `optional` as the `co_await` expression type and whatever the return value type of the function it is used within.

The VS2015 implementation of `co_await` provides this machinery for `co_await`ing on `std::future`. But it doesn't have that support for `optional` or other random types. You'd have to build it yourself, which none of the posts you cited point out.